# How to check s3 object size using golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have implemented a function to download an object from AWS S3 bucket. This works fine. But I need to display a download progress bar. For this I need to know the size of the object beforehand according to [here](https://github.com/cheggaaa/pb)
. Does anyone know how to get the object size?

Here is my code.

```
func DownloadFromS3Bucket(bucket, item, path string) {
    file, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(path, item))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in downloading from file: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(constants.AWS_REGION), Credentials: credentials.AnonymousCredentials},
    )

    // Create a downloader with the session and custom options
    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess, func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
        d.PartSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024 // 64MB per part
        d.Concurrency = 6
    })

    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(item),
        })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in downloading from file: %v \n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Download completed", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of the [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.HeadObject), which contains the [header `Content-Length`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html#RESTObjectHEAD-responses-examples).

> HeadObject API operation for Amazon Simple Storage Service.
>
> The HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning
>   the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested
>   in an object's metadata. To use HEAD, you must have READ access to the
>   object.

Comment: Could you please give an example using go. I couldn't find anywhere which its implemented in go.

Comment: @MadhukaWickramapala There is an example, see the link, try the request and print the response

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
headObj := s3.HeadObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key: aws.String(key),
}
result, err := S3.HeadObject(&headObj)
if err != nil {
  // handle error
}
return aws.Int64Value(result.ContentLength)
```

Comment: perfect but return will not work so, easier to just use fmt.Println like
 fmt.Println(result)

Answer (score 0):

With aws-sdk-go-v2, you have the content length right in the `GetObjectResponse`. This code snippet is for `aws-sdk-go-v2` before v1 tags.

```
// s3client is *s3.Client
// s3 qualifier is "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"

req := s3client.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
})
resp, err := req.Send(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
body := resp.Body // the io.ReadCloser that streams the object data
clen := aws.Int64Value(resp.ContentLength) // the content length
```

Since `aws-sdk-go-v2` v1, the method is [`GetObject`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#Client.GetObject) and the response is [`GetObjectOutput`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#GetObjectOutput) but it still has `ContentLength` field.