# Why downloading in memory is slower than downloding in file system from aws s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am using AWS gosdk to download from some bucket. Below are the two implementation of download

1. Download to file

```
func (a *AwsClient) DownloadToFile(ctx context.Context, objectKey string) (string, error) {
    params := &awsS3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(a.bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    }

    downloadPath := "some/valid/path"
    f, err := os.Create(downloadPath)
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = a.downloader.Download(ctx, f, params)
    return downloadPath, err
}
```

2. Download to memory

```
func (a *AwsClient) DownloadToMemory(ctx context.Context, objectKey string) (string, error) {
    params := &awsS3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(a.bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    }

    buffer := manager.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})  
    _, err = a.downloader.Download(ctx, buffer, params)
    return buffer.Bytes(), err
}
```

For 100 MB file, download in memory is taking 30s and download in file system is taking only 8 seconds. My expectation was memory download should be much faster. My system (Apple M1, Ventura, 8GB RAM) has enough free RAM, so that is not the problem. Can someone help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: Can you be more precise with `My System`? Is it your PC, MAC or an EC2?

Comment: Macos ventura, 8GB RAM

Comment: You did not close the file. Without closing the file nothing might ever get written to disk.

Comment: Sorry @volker, I didn't get you. I am closing the file via `defer f.Close()` in the first method. Did you mean something else?

Comment: It seems I missed that. Unrelated but important: You must handle the error from Close.

Comment: The original code has that error handling. I removed it here to make the code small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading a big S3 Object into a dynamic buffer is quite inefficient. That buffer is reallocated many times to handle 100M of data and multiple download threads. That memory reallocation takes lots of CPU time.

Try to allocate 100M at the beginning instead of using an empty slice of bytes.

You can use [S3.HeadObject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65710928/1420332) to get Object Length in real time if size of object is unknown.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I was debugging my code for days.

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago. Glad that you can solve it.